# How can I crawl a bunch of links on a root website using Scrapy?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl a covid-19 statistics website which has a bunch of links to pages regarding the statistics for different countries. The links all have a class name that makes them easy to access using css selectors ('mt_a'). There is no continuity between the countries so if you are on the webpage for one of them, there is no link to go to the next country. I am a complete beginner to scrapy and I'm not sure what I should do if my goal is to scrape all the (200 ish) links listed on the root page for the same few pieces of information. Any guidance on what I should be trying to do would be appreciated.

The link I'm trying to scrape: https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/
(scroll down to see country links)

Comment: If you found a solution to be helpful please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is create two spiders. One would parse the home page and extract all specific links to country pages href within anchor tags, i.e. `href="country/us/"` and then create full urls from these relative links so that you get a proper url like `https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/us/`.

Then the second spider is given the list of all country urls and then goes on to crawl all individual pages and extract information from those.

For example, you get a list of urls from the first spider:

```
urls = ['https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/us/',
'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/russia/']
```

Then in the second spider you give that list to the `start_urls` attribute.

Comment: Ok thank you! Yea this makes sense I have managed to create a list of all the links with just basic string manipulation I will look into how I can pass that list into the start_urls of another spider.

Comment: Glad this helped. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think others have already answered the question, but here is the page for [Link extractors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html).

Comment: Ok thank you! I was relying on the similar posts it shows you when you are making your post and since I didn't see any question sounding like mine I just posted.